# .Net SDK Framework 4.5.1 registry key

Tags: .net, sdk, frameworks

I have been working on updating a tool which allows users to select the SDK version and bit type to run .Net Framework SDK tools.

To do this getting the installation location of the most up to date SDK is required and we go back all the way to v1.0. So far I have found the following and looking for confirmation.

v1.0, v1.1, and v2.0 framework installation folder registry keys are located under the respective registry platform version. i.e. the locating of the 64 bit installation folder is a 64 bit registry entry, where the 32 bit installation directory is a 32 bit registry key.

```
Examples:

Windows XP:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework 

Windows 7 64 bit (v2.0 only):
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\.NETFramework\v2.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\.NETFramework\v2.0
```

v3.0, v3.5, v4.0 framework installation folders have 32 bit installation folder and 64 bit installation folder in both the 32 bit and 64 bit registry keys. This makes things simple enough for these versions. Just read the key as the OS bit version and your right.

```
Examples:

Windows 7 64 bit:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKNetFx35Tools
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKNetFx35Tools-x64
```

v4.5, v4.5.1 framework installation folders seem to only exist under a 32 bit registry key. Even though there is a 64 bit installation the registry key only exists under the 3264WoW node, which means you have to read it like your a 32 bit application.

```
Examples:

Windows 7 64 bit:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x64
```

Note any reference to Wow6432Node would be read using the registry read with a 32 bit flag when on 64 bit windows. I never ready the Wow6432Node directly, just specify to the registry object which section to read from.

This seems to be fair to complex, making me think I haven't got it correct. Also I haven't been able to locate any definitive documentation on .Net SDK installation locations.

So the question is there anything I have missed here or have incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no better solution that read 8.1A path z Wow6432Node

```
public static string GetSdk81Path(string sdkIdent)
        {
            string regPath = Path.Combine(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\", sdkIdent);
            using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32))
            using (RegistryKey regKey  = baseKey.OpenSubKey(regPath, false))
            {
                if (regKey == null)
                {
                    throw new RegistryKeyNotFoundException("Registry key not found.", baseKey, regPath);
                }
                return regKey.GetValue("InstallationFolder").ToString();
            }
        }
```